# Using not() instead of hasclass()?

Tags: jquery

```
if ($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").not('checked')) {

}
```

is there anything wrong on this? instead of using hasClass I use not(), checking whether there is any checked class..

Comment: is `checked` your class name? If not, you would want to do it like SmokeyPHP has mentioned above.

Comment: For classes, prepend with dot. For the checked state, prepend with colon (as others have suggested)

Comment: @Harry - The code as shown is checking for a tag name (element type), not a class. But yes, either way is wrong.

Comment: FYI, there's a specific checkbox selector, instead of `"input[type=checkbox]"` you can just use `":checkbox"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to test the negation of [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) - testing the element does not have the specified class

Since you are looking for a boolean value, you need to use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if ($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':not(.checked)')) {
}
```

=

```
if (!$(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").hasClass('checked')) {
}
```

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) is a filter method, it returns a jQuery wrapper set which does not satisfy the given selector.

Comment: Chaining isn't actually required btw, plus there's a specific checkbox selector: selector can just be `find(":checkbox:not(.checked)")`